# Where to store session data, cookies vs services Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cookies, angularjs-service

As we know, services in angularjs are singleton, so they being pass by reference and we can store data on it to use it in others app sections.(like cookies).

In my app, users can select their city and I need access that info in others places of the app, so I need store it in memory.

Told that, Should I use services or cookies to store that kind of session data. There is some bad practice with using services to do that ? or is there any problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Okey, I think I got it.

If I need to remember my data session even when the user leaves the app, I need to store it using cookies not services. Because services does not persists and cookies does.

In my case, I needed to store user location and remember it, so the best approach is to use cookies.